# How to print the output of variables in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

This might be a very basic question but I am stuck with it for quite some time now. I have four variables with some values and I want to put it into a data frame. I am using the below code but not getting any results. Please help

[code details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxCCY.png)

Comment: Hi! It is better to add code here instead of using screenshot. Besides you should add any error you get or desired output you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create new dataframe with columns A, B, C, D:

```
import pandas as pd

A=5*5
B=6*6
C=7*7
D=8*8

data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5*5], 'B': [6*6], 'C': [7*7], 'D': [8*8]})
data
print(data)
```

Comment: replace that lists with the variable.

Comment: As in pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'D': D}) ? Yes, that's a good option as well.

Comment: If you do not replace with variables, what's the use of variables?

Comment: You're correct - I'm using the OP's original code format. But the variables could be deleted without problem.